# How to handle missing values in a bootstrap resampling distribution?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, missing-data, resampling

I am creating a function that calculates point and interval estimates for a statistic of interest. I get the interval estimate through bootstrapping. However, it occasionally occurs that the statistic is undefined (`NaN`) or not calculable (`NA`) in one or more bootstrap resamples. This typically occurs with smaller or skewed samples that might result in a division by zero.

**How should I handle these "missing values" when calculating the interval estimate? Is it defensible to simply drop them and calculate the interval for the non-missing values?**

Any tips on how to communicate to the users of my function that this has occurred? Would it be enough to report the number of bootstrap resamples that were non-missing?

Comment: In my opinion you can not just drop na values. Division by zero theoretically should be infinity. Quantiles which may form your CI will be different if you drop them.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a problem in your programming or underlying analysis.  You will need to give us more information on your statistic of interest and what you are estimating to be sure.

Comment: @GermanDemidov, Very late response, but re-reading your helpful comment, I am thinking that perhaps I can just code these NaN or NAs as Inf and still calculate the interval estimates via quantiles.